# How do I go about converting this data into a choropleth world map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, choropleth, datamaps, react-d3

I have a dynamically generated object with shape:

`{ Hungary: 10, Iceland: 16, Israel: 5, ...}`

How do I go about converting this data into a choropleth world map?

I have tried [react-simple-maps](https://github.com/zcreativelabs/react-simple-maps) but it uses an extremely large json as the data source and there's no documentation for a simple mapping from a countries count object.